# How to use prototypes such as modules in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, prototype

I create a folder called helpers, and inside that, create the array.js file

Inside my array.js, i have this code:

```
Array.prototype.inArray() {
  for(var j in this) {
    if (this[j] === arguments[0]) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

And i want be able to use like a module:

```
myArray.inArray(myargument);
```

but when i try, this error show up in the terminal:

```
path.js:360
        throw new TypeError('Arguments to path.join must be strings');
              ^
TypeError: Arguments to path.join must be strings
```

What i am doing wrong? I follow this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11862971/how-to-use-a-prototypes-such-as-modules-in-node-js)

Forgetting my problem for a minute.. I wonder if there is a side effect of creating prototypes like modules.

Thanks.

UPDATE:

I am trying to use the prototype in other file, called i18nConf.js:

```
var self = {
    setLanguage: function(language) {
        if (global.config.locales.langs.inArray(language)) {
            global.lang = require(__dirname + '/' + language);
            global.lang.current = language;
        } else {
            global.lang = require(__dirname + '/' + global.config.site.language);
            global.lang.current = global.config.site.language;
        }
    }
};

module.exports = self;
```

Comment: o, sorry.. i didn't understood your question haha.. i will include the full code here.

Comment: How are you requiring the array file

Comment: You have to require the array.js file somewhere onces

Comment: What is behind the mix of function invoke and declaration?

Comment: i am not requiring the array, should i? In this particular answer -> http://stackoverflow.com/a/11863620/4520762 the user is not requiring anything.

Comment: Don't iterate arrays with `for...in` loops. Do not use `arguments` unless it's completely necessary, in this case you can just declare an argument. To find a value in an array, [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) is faster than iterating manually. You can also use [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes), introduced in ECMAScript 7.

Comment: You have to require that file somewhere atleast to execute the file

Comment: you are 100% right @MukeshAgarwal, if you want win some points, please write a answer.

Comment: @DRX: Posted the answer, Thanks

Comment: to make prototypes extensions more explicit, i would suggest something more like this http://stackoverflow.com/a/11863567/273743

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Require the array.js file atleast once

like

```
require('pathToArraj.js');
```